# Can a Cyberdisc always ignore a proximity mine if it hasn't been alerted?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I started up XCOM:EW for the first time in months last night and saw one of my favorite (read: most hated) bugs:

1. Mimetic skin dude out in front
2. Unalerted Cyberdisc spotted within range with drones
3. Mech drops proximity mine right into the middle of the disk-drone group
4. Disc or drone moves on its patrol pattern, detonating mine, blowing up scenery, triggering its alert cutscene
5. Disc squad deploys but none of its members have taken any damage

So, the question is: will this happen every time?  Should I make sure to only drop mines on disc squads after they're alerted?  Or are they generally a waste?

In fairness, proximity mines are joy itself when it comes to the EXALT....

Comment: That's always been my experience. It's worth triggering the alert cutscene first.

Comment: Cyberdisc shouldn't trigger the mine iirc, they're supposed to be floating

Answer (score -1):

Are you on console? I am not certain, but I do remember reading that it's a known console bug where unalerted enemies don't get damaged unless you directly fire at them.

It was brought up in the context of firing a rocket into a known enemy nest in the fog of war, but I assume it would also apply to your situation since the only difference is the absence of fog of war.

Comment: No this is the PC game (on steam)